# Conditional Eloquent relationship can be written but can't be read (eager load)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships

Using Laravel 5.3, I have a method in my `Order` Eloquent model that returns a `belongsToMany` or a `hasMany` relationship depending on the value of a `type` char attribute value.

`Order` is itself a child of a `MasterOrder` model as a one to many relationship.

```
                 ---------------
                 * MasterOrder *
                 -------+-------
                        |
                       O2M                             
                        |
       +----------------+------------------+
       |                |                  |
   ----+-------     ----+-------      -----+------
   *  Order   *     *  Order   *      *  Order   *
   * Type = O *     * Type = C *      * Type = S *
   -+----------     -+----------      -+----------
    |     Offer      |CreditPack       |  Shipment
    |                |                 | 
   M2M              M2M               O2M
```

The relation in the `Order` model is the following

```php
public function items()
{
    $types = [
        'S' => Shipment::class,
        'O' => Discount::class,
        'C' => CreditPack::class
    ];

    if ($this->type == 'C') {
        return $this->belongsToMany($types['C'], 'credit_pack_order')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    if ($this->type == 'O') {
        return $this->belongsToMany($types['O'], 'discounts')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    return $this->hasMany($types[$this->type]);
}
```

When inserting the data I am able to `attach()` offers and credit packs, and `create()` shipments using my `items()` method and it works without any issue.
Data is persisted in the database and everything is where I need it to be.

The problem is that I can't read through `items()` if I eager load my relationships starting from the `MasterOrder` model (even though I start from there when I insert the data).

I can read `Order` data eager loading it from `MasterOrder`, but **it seems like it can't read `Order` attributes when it tries to load `items()`**.

It is able to read them, instead, if I start from `Order`.

Is there something I can do to avoid querying the database twice for every order?
Can anyone please explain me why do this happen?

Comment: It looks to me as though you may want to look at using a polymorphic relationship on your models - this is hinted at by the fact that you're using conditionals to setup relationships.

Comment: @Oddman I can't, one of the relationships differs from the others. `Shipment` requires a one to many, while the others are both many to many.

Comment: There's one of 2 ways you can do it - either have separate methods for each relationship (my preferred method), or use a polymorphic relationship and treat them all that way. 

The problem is that as you have it, items() will return different collections of objects, and that's a domain boundary concern. It shouldn't be doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround while talking about the issue in a italian developers Facebook group.

Substantially I can tell the method what `type` comes out from the order as an argument of the function. This way it will know what to answer even if it didn't load the attributes.

The relation becomes:

```php
public function items($type = null)
{
    if ($type != null) {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    $types = [
        'S' => Shipment::class,
        'O' => Discount::class,
        'C' => CreditPack::class
    ];

    if ($this->type == 'C') {
        return $this->belongsToMany($types['C'], 'credit_pack_order')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    if ($this->type == 'O') {
        return $this->belongsToMany($types['O'], 'discounts')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    return $this->hasMany($types[$this->type]);
}
```

and I retrieve the data using

```php
$masterorder = auth()->user()->orders()        // orders() is a User->MasterOrder
    ->where('reference', '=', $reference)      // hasMany relation
    ->first();

$details = $masterorder->orders()->get()
    ->map(function ($order) {
        $order->items = $order->items($order->type)->get()->toArray();
        return $order;
    });
```

Comment: I would still highly recommend that you change what you're doing here - these are 3 separate relationships and should be treated as such.

Comment: I understand what you mean and I thank you for the suggestion, but I've uniformed the output and I don't care to break the SOLID in this case. I'm probably going to refactor in the near future.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by break the SOLID, but fair enough.